# Extracting existing and non existing values from 2 columns using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am new to pandas and I am trying to get a list of values that exists in both columns, values that exist in column A, values that only exist in column B.

My .csv file looks like this:

```
A        B
AAA      ZZZ
BBB      BBB
CCC      EEE
DDD      FFF
EEE      AAA
         DDD
GGG      HHH
JJJ
```

Columns have a different length and my outcome would be 3 lists or one csv that I would ouput having 3 columns, one for items existing in both columns, one for items existing in only A column and one for items existing in only B column.

```
IN BOTH      IN COLUMN A     IN COLUMN B
AAA          CCC             ZZZ
BBB          GGG             FFF
DDD          JJJ             HHH
EEE
(empty one)
```

I have tried using .isin() module but it returns true of false rather than the actual list.

```
existing_in_both = df_column_a.isin(df_column_b)
```

And I do not know how I should try to extract values that only exist in either column A or B.

Thank you for your suggestions.

My actual .csv has the following:

```
id clickout_id timestamp click_id click_type
1 123abc       2019-11-25 c51c56d1 1
1 123dce       2019-11-25 c51c5fs1 12
```

and other file is looking like this:

```
timestamp id gid type
2019-11-25 1 c51c56d1 2
2019-11-25 1 c51c5fs1 2
```

And I am trying to compare click_id from first file and gid from the second file.

When I print out using your answer I get the header names as answers rather than the values from the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `set`s with intersection and difference, then for new `DataFrame` are used `Series`, because different lengths of outputs:

```
a = set(df.A)
b = set(df.B)

df = pd.DataFrame({'IN BOTH': pd.Series(list(a & b)),
                   'IN COLUMN A': pd.Series(list(a - b)),
                   'IN COLUMN B': pd.Series(list(b - a))})
print (df)
  IN BOTH IN COLUMN A IN COLUMN B
0     DDD         CCC         FFF
1     BBB         GGG         ZZZ
2     AAA         JJJ         HHH
3                 NaN         NaN
4     EEE         NaN         NaN
```

Or use [`numpy.intersect1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html) with [`numpy.setdiff1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'IN BOTH': pd.Series(np.intersect1d(df.A, df.B)),
                   'IN COLUMN A': pd.Series(np.setdiff1d(df.A, df.B)),
                   'IN COLUMN B': pd.Series(np.setdiff1d(df.B, df.A))})
print (df)
  IN BOTH IN COLUMN A IN COLUMN B
0                 CCC         FFF
1     AAA         GGG         HHH
2     BBB         JJJ         ZZZ
3     DDD         NaN         NaN
4     EEE         NaN         NaN
```

Comment: Hi, using the first method only headers are taken into account, not the actual values.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - What return for you `print (a)` ?

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question with the .csv I am using.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - then create DataFrame for each file by `df1 = pd.read_csv(file1)` and `a = set(df1['click_id'])`, `df2 = pd.read_csv(file2)` and `b = set(df2['gid'])`

Comment: Getting the following error - `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'bool'`

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - ok, if use second solution it working?

Comment: Yes, just tried that and it works, thank you for your help. Any ideas why would the first solution wouldnt work?

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - hmmm, not idea. Maybe some mixed types - boolean with numeric and strings